# Acronyms in LaTeX with lowercase and uppercase plurals and singular forms?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I am using the Glossaries package to write acronyms (i.e. abbreviations) using \gls{}, \Gls{}, acrlong{}, acrlongpl{}, acrshort{}, acrshortpl{} ... the whole family. I have 2 pages that appear in my thesis. One for the acronyms and one for the glossaries. In other words, I am also using the Glossaries package to write Glossaries entries in the sense of definitions like what follows:

```
\newglossaryentry{QoE.Glossary}%  label
{%
type=definition,% glossary type
name=Quality of Experience,% how it will appear inside the Glossary List 
text={Quality of Experience (QoE)},% how it will appear inside the text
description={\textit{``is  blah blah blah''}~\cite{le2012}.},% Description
sort={quality}%   
}
```

The way I structure my acronyms (abbreviations) is as follows:

```
\newacronym[shortplural={PMs}, longplural={Progressive Meshes}]{PM.Acronym}{PM}{Progressive Mesh}
```

That works fine except I need more cases for the Acronyms or abbreviations.

The ability to use the singular form Acronym (capitalizing the first letters of Words) and plural form acronym (capitalizing the first letters of Words). But what if we want also to use the lowercase versions of both of these cases while still working with the uppercase versions? How can we do that?

I saw another thread  on stackexchange but did not tackle all the cases I need (just said how to do it in lowercase (with no uppercase).

To recap kindly I need a way to solve this using the Short/Long and Full versions of Acronyms with 4 scenarios: (1) Singular (all words lowercase, in case of abbreviations: all characters lowercase), (2) Plural (all words lowercase, in case of abbreviations: all characters lowercase), (3) Singular (First Letter of every word Capitalized, in case of abbreviations: all characters uppercase), (4) Plural (First Letter of every word Capitalized, in case of abbreviations: all characters uppercase) and yet all this with the normal use that comes from using the commands \acrxxx where xxx could be 'short', 'long' or 'full' as you know and \gls and \Gls.

So in the example I gave: how can I print: "progressive mesh", "progressive meshes", "pm" - all lowercase? Since from the example given: I can print "Progressive Mesh", "Progressive Meshes", "Progressive Mesh (PM)", "Progressive Meshes (PMs)",  "PMs" and "PM".

Could that be done in glossaries, or glossaries-extra packages and how? If not, any suggestion for a neat solution in another package or using macros?

Comment: Have you tried to use the package `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}`with the option `firstuc`

Comment: No I haven't. does it contain all I need? And I should mention my thesis is literally scattered with commands like \gls{..}, \Gls{...}, \acrfull{..} etc... will that break their usage. Thanks!

Comment: I see it did not break anything. Can you kindly provide an example if you know of how all my cases (lowercase/uppercase...) could be included? Thanks

Comment: You might have to customize the behaviour with a few macros, but it should be compatible since `glossaries-extra` is an extension of `glossaries`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try  things our and see works. Then later if I found a solution based on your suggestion, I will post it here in case other people want a neat solution based on glossaries and glossaries-extra packages.